# Setting distance attribute on model using Postgis + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis

I'm using postgis to sort data based on the distance away from the user. Since postgis calculates the distance before giving the information back is there a way that it can set the value to the distance attribute when giving me back the information? I don't want this to be stored in the database and just want it to be set when retrieving. This is what I am using to do the sort in my model. Thanks in advance.

```
scope :distance, ->(userLat, userLng) { 
order(
%{
ST_Distance_Sphere(
  ST_GeomFromEWKT(
    'SRID=4326;POINT(' || properties.lng || ' ' || properties.lat || ')'
  ),
  ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)')
)
} % [userLng, userLat])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if the value is being calculated by Postgres, then Postgres will obviously have to calculate it during the sort.  If you are dead set on not denormalizing your db with the distance calculation as a field then you can make a db view and sit your model on top of that.

```
create view properties_distance as 
  select ST_Distance_Sphere(
    ST_GeomFromEWKT(
      'SRID=4326;POINT(' || properties.lng || ' ' || properties.lat || ')'
    ),
    ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)')
  ) as distance, lng, lat from properties;
```

Comment: What do you mean by denormalizing? I'm trying to avoid having the field saved since each query should have a different distance result based on user location. And since I'm using rails as my api is there another approach instead of a view?

Comment: A view is basically a denormalized view of your db.  Due to the fact that you must calculate it within the DB (using Postgres GEO) on each fetch means you either calculate it in your select clause as you are doing or leverage a db view to do it for you.  They both amount to pretty much the same thing.  The view approach will look cleaner but will not be faster